# More than one component for IVTEditLink editor in VirtualTreeView

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Is there a way how to add more than one component into VirtualTreeView's IVTEditLink editor ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking here. If you want to compose your `IVTEditLink` editor from, I don't know `TPanel` and two `TEdit` boxes, then it is possible; the only thing you should have in your mind is to implement the `IVTEditLink` interface for that panel and handle also the events for those edit boxes - if you would like e.g. to cancel editing when you `OnExit` the edit box, then you have to `CancelEditNode` in that event.

Comment: Or if you are asking if you can implement more than one `IVTEditLink` interface, e.g. `TComboBox` for one column and `TDateTimePicker` for another one, then just case the columns in the `OnCreateEditor` and create the editor you want to use ;)

Comment: thank you for your reply. if it would be possible, i would mark your post as an good answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a standalone form as an editor container and leave the `IVTEditLink` concept for this purpose because:

- if you use e.g. `TPanel` as an editor component container then you should consider to choose the right `Parent` of that `TPanel`; the editor with many fields may overlap either the bounds rectangle of your virtual tree or even bounds of your form
- it's much more easier to implement `OnDeactivate` event to a form than to `TPanel` component
- you can leave the `IVTEditLink` concept at all because it looses its sense here; the `IVTEditLink` was designed for specific node and column editors rather than for the whole nodes; you can simply open the form editor when the `OnEditing` event arrives, or at double click event etc.

But if I didn't convince you of leaving the `IVTEditLink` concept for node editing of more than one column then you can check [`this example`](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=198cbd603f4d4d09&resid=198CBD603F4D4D09!141&parid=198CBD603F4D4D09!140) for the implementation of a form as an editor for `IVTEditLink` interface.

Comment: Very nice example application.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create your custom editors in `OnCreateEditor` event. Because this event provides `Column` parameter you can create different editors for different columns. E.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.OnCreateEditor(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; out EditLink: IVTEditLink);
begin
  case Column of
    0: EditLink := TColorEditLink.Create;
    1: EditLink := TFontEditLink.Create;
  //etc..
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OP wants the first case of my comments; to compose one editor from more than one component, not to use different editors for different columns.

Comment: Question is very unclear then. OP needs to edit his question to make it more clear what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: Agree, that's why I've asked for the explanation in my comments ;)